# Can an Indian ETA expiry date be extended

Tags: india, visa-expiration, eta, e-visas

I have received my e-visa to India, however, due to unforeseen circumstances I have to travel on Nov 23, landing in Mumbai on Nov 25. My ETA expiry date is Nov 22, can I still travel.?

Answer (score 2):

No, an Indian e-visa (tourist visa) cannot be extended.

From [evisa India](https://www.evisaindia.org/renew-extend-visa-for-india/):

> Once you have an approved e-Visa you can travel around the country and explore its lively cities, taste its delicious food, and more. **Just note that an e-Visa for India cannot be extended and that your passport needs to be valid for six months.**

If you enter the country you will almost certainly not be allowed to enter as your visa has expired and you have no authority to enter the country.

You will need to apply for a new visa. If asked why your old visa was unused you can say that you had a change in circumstances, just because of this a new visa won't be denied. The application will be considered on its own merts.